# Expand sharepoint rest api to document folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Below is my current filter for my rest API call and this works:

```
?$select=Id,Title,ProductNo,Description,Image,Version_Id,Version_nr&$filter=(Version_Id eq "+Version+")".
```

Now I've created a new Document library called `ProductFiles`.

In my `Part` List, I created a lookup field to `ProductFiles` (called Files) so I can link multiple ProductFiles to a list item in `Part`.

When I'm trying to add the `expand` to my filter it don't work:

```
?$select=Id,Title,ProductNo,Description,Image,Version_Id,Version_nr,ProductFiles/Files&$expand=ProductFiles/Files&$filter=(Version_Id eq "+Version+")".
```

Error:

> The field or property 'ProductFiles' does not exist.

Can someone point out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
?$select=Id,Title,ProductNo,Description,Image,Version_Id,Version_nr,Files/Title&$expand=Files&$filter=(Version_Id eq "+Version+")
```

Typically it should be `$select=lookupfield/fieldtoexpandinparent$expand=lookupfield`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work, but a file in a document library it does not fill title but name, and name not receivable, Is there some way I can get the name also?

Comment: You cant expand all properties of lookup field...Especially Name(FileLeafRef) this of type 'File' so you cant expand it.. as a workaround force 'Title' field as mandatory or design a simple OOTB WF to fill the Title dynamically...